# How to fetch 1 table users details using 2 table in php pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Hi can anyone help am trying fetch all user data from database using php and pdo method

i have two tables 1 table for users data, 2 for connected users id's ,

i want fetch only connected users profiles when users id exit in 2 table.

first i checked 2 table whether user id there or not. example a user connected to 2 other users , i got users ids and implode into array. then i used to check 1 table `Where In (:usid)` but its fetching only one user details

how can i fetch all details using 2 database

```
    public function usrconnectedall(){
        $bngusername2 = $_SESSION['bngusername'];
        $this->query("SELECT * FROM bng_users WHERE bng_username=:bngusername2");
        $this->bind(":bngusername2", $bngusername2);
        $row = $this->getSingleRow();

        //First Method (Requested) user profile id
        $bngrequesteduserid = $row['id'];

        $this->query("SELECT * FROM bng_connect WHERE bng_requesteduser_id=:bngrequesteduserid");
        $this->bind(":bngrequesteduserid", $bngrequesteduserid);
        $row2 = $this->resultSet();

        foreach ($row2 as $k) {
          $test[] = $k['bng_connecteduser_id'];
        }
        $usid = implode(',', $test);


        $this->query("SELECT * FROM bng_users WHERE id IN (:usid)");
        $this->bind(":usid", $usid);
        $row3 = $this->resultSet();

        foreach ($row3 as $a){
           echo $a['bng_username'];
        }


      }
```

Comment: Use `JOIN` for get data from multiple table related to each other

Comment: `SELECT * FROM bng_connect INNER JOIN bng_users ON id = bngrequesteduserid;` Is this what you're looking for...?

Comment: first am fetching data using username getting connected users id, based on users ids implode in array.  based on implode data i need to search users data in first table, i dont want join them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answer i found. now am able to fetch users data

```
$usid = implode(',', $test);

    $this->query("SELECT * FROM bng_users WHERE  FIND_IN_SET (id, :usid)");
    $this->bind(':usid', $usid);
    $row3 = $this->resultSet();

    return $row3;
```

Comment: Was this intended to be an edit to your question? Because it certainly doesn't provide an answer to it, yet you posted it in the Answers section. Use the "edit" button under your question to add extra info. Thanks.